# Display summary form through Modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Need to create food ordering system. 
I'm quite stuck, where I would like to summarized the user's choice in **modal** form before storing in my database. It is said that modal is recommended inorder not to restart all over again using other page.

Its in wizard template where clicking **NEXT** $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success');, it works fine and the choices doesn't reset if I go back to the first step:

Here's what I've got so far.
HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form role="form" id="showchoices" name="showchoices" method="post" onsubmit="return entry_check()" action="/user/ps/add/">

     <div id="step-11"><fieldset>
    <input type="radio" id="food1" name="burger" value="bigburger"/> BB
    <input type="radio" id="food2" name="burger" value="reg_burger"/> RB </fieldset> </div>

    <div id="step-22"> <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" id="drink1" name="drink" value="coca-cola"/> CC
    <input type="radio" id="drink2" name="drink" value="juice"/> J </fieldset> </div>

    <div id="step-33"><input type="text" id="other_food" name="other"/> </div>
 </form>

<input type="button" name="btn" value="Review" id="review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con_rev" class="btn btn-primary" />

<!--  pop out modal  -->
<div class="modal fade" id="con_rev" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">Confirm Order</div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p> Your Burger: <span id="burger_type"></span> </p>
                <p> Your Drinks: <span id="drink_type"></span> </p>
                <p> Others: <span id="otherfood"> </span></p></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button> <a href="" id="submit" class="btn btn-success success">Submit</a> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my JS, which in same file HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#review').click(function () {
        $('#burger_type').html($('#burger').val());
        $('#drink_type').html($('#drink').val());
        $('#otherfood').html($('#other_food').val());
    }); </script>
```

So only my "other_food" does displays what text you've input, others won't.  I don't know how to check in radio mode.

Thank you in advance, I'm no expert in JS or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$('#burger_type').html($('input[name="burger"]:checked').val());`

basicly javascript doesn't read the value of radio buttons in a simple way.
what we're doing is getting all the inputs named `burger` and filtering (`:` pseudo class) only the one who is checked - i.e the selected option.

Comment: thank you! I really don't know yet checking stuffs. incase for selecting options .. should I change checked to _selected_  or remain as _checked_ ?

Comment: my pleasure! you mean `<select>` `<option>` ? in that case `val()` works as expected, the problem is only with `radio` and `checkbox`

Comment: yes the select and option . does this codes applicable to it? `$('#burger_type').html($('#burger').val());`

Comment: if the `<select>` has `id="burger"` this code will work